# How to Insert a Record and load this record on select option without page refreshing in php using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to add product record under a product category. But if expected category not found on the select option I don't want cancel from this step I just want to add a category from this step. If I add the category then it will load select option without page refreshing.

[Here I have to select option field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgR5W.jpg)

[when I click on add category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogwim.jpg)

After saving category it will load on the select option field

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. so that everyone can easily get your scenario.

Comment: you need to use Ajax to add and to append the option to your select. are you using any front-end framework or jQuery at least?

Answer (score 0):

First use a different php page to call only options in select.
Then,

```
<script>
$("#id_of_submit_button").click(function(){

    var category = $('#id_of_input').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'page_to_insert_category.php',
    data: {category:category},
    success:function(data){
         //call the function which you used to get the options again
    }

});
</script>
```

You will get the value of category in php page as

```
  $_POST['category']
```

Answer (score 0):

1.on click of submit button call an ajax 
2. on same controller after save write logic for updated records in desc order and return in response updated array.
3. in success of ajax write logic for select last id record. ex. ($('#your_id [value=3]').attr('selected', 'true');)
4. trigger update on that select dropdown variable. ex. $('#mySelect').val('ab').trigger("updated");